# Is there a way to enter a non-space "invisible" letter in Windows?

Tags: windows, gmail

Gmail lets you have hierarchy in tags. In other words, you can nest tags.

But, in displaying nested tags in the left-panel, Gmail only indents nested tags down to the second level. From the third level and down, the tags are indented the same, making it impossible to discern the hierarchy based on the indentation.

I've been trying different things to overcome this, to no avail.

My last hope is to insert a non-space, "invisible" character that will create the illusion of an indentation.  (i.e., one "invisible" character in front of the third level, two such invisible characters in front of the fourth level, etc.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Does "space" not work or "tab"?

Comment: Neither works in Gmail as "invisible" character. Gmail ignores them.

Comment: Could be that you can only nest tags so far into the hierarchy.

Comment: By "tag" you mean "label"?

Comment: I have nested labels 4 deep and I can also insert alt 0160 into the labal name

Comment: @ DavidPostill, I also have nested labels that are 4 levels deep. But the question is, when you insert Alt 0160 into the label name, does Gmail recognize it as a "space", or does Gmail ignore Alt 0160 and indents 3rd and 4th-level labels flush with the 2nd level?

Comment: Yes, I meant "label".. I always get confused...

Answer (score 1):

There is such a thing as [a “No-Break Space”](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) and [as Wikipedia explains it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

> In word processing and digital typesetting, a non-breaking space ("
>   "), also known as a no-break space or non-breakable space (NBSP), is a
>   variant of the space character that prevents an automatic line break
>   (line wrap) at its position.

And according to that Wikipedia entry it can be manually entered as Unicode by doing this key combo:

> <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

More general info on manually [entering Unicode characters in Windows can be found here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).

Comment: Yes, I read the Wikipedia article too, but Gmail simply ignores the "alt + 1060" non-breaking space in a tag name.

Comment: I have, but it didn't work.